# load multiple videos in a single flash file

Tags: flash, video

I have a swf file, which plays 6 videos one after the other in a loop. This file is very huge so it is taking more than a minute for it to start playing after the page finished loading. I have taken the original video file, and split it into 6 files. I plan to have 6 tiles in the flash file as soon as the page loads, and when some tile is clicked, the video is loaded dynamically only that video or swf file so that it saves the loading time and once this is done, i want it to revert back to the main page with tiles. I am just starting off with flash and I have no clue how this is possible in flash. I am not asking for code, i need some tips to get started. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[an example with video (on wonderfl.net it's possible to edit the source code and have it compiled online)](http://wonderfl.net/c/3dVV)

[here's a research of synchronising several video streams with screenshots and source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052038/how-to-synchronize-multiple-video-streams-in-actionscript/4052831#4052831)
if you need a sample app - try to describe it in the comments and i'll try to post it on wonderfl

Comment: thanks for your reply mate... i am looking for something that is there on http://www.aimaawards.com/... that flash file which has 6 different videos...

Comment: @ Scorpion King - it's an swf with 6 video thumbnails (containing a screenshot and text each) and a player (based on `NetConnection`, `NetStream` and `Video` classes and with some gui). each thumbnail is a button that makes the player load an external video file and become visible

Comment: if there any way you could give me a sample like the one you just gave as an answer to this post?

Comment: @ Scorpion King - going to write it tomorrow

Comment: appreciate you considering to do it :)

Comment: man...thanks a lot. I will make the changes to make it look the way i wanted it to be.